# Update a value into a JSON string with Ruby ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

Sorry to ask this question but I'm really newbie with Ruby and I need help to update several records on mu database.

Starting with the code below. Could you help me to write a console query or instruction that help me to change the value of the "size"=>"001" to "size"=>"400".

```
2.1.2 :050 > orders.first
 => #<Order id: 3193, qty: 3193, data: {"size"=>"001", "barcode"=>"123456789", "barcode_type"=>"128"}, order_item_id: 473, sub_item_id: 001, created_at: "2015-07-26 05:03:32", updated_at: "2015-07-26 05:03:32">
```

Then what should I do if I want to update all orders, not only the first one?

Comment: Do you use serialize attribute on data?

Comment: data is string column?

Comment: The format of the column is JSON

Comment: Is that a string column ( that happens to contain JSON data) or a JSON/jsonb column (as supported by recent versions of MySQL, Postgres etc)

Comment: JSON/jsonb column (as supported by recent versions of MySQL, Postgres etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing the solution of M Kumar I found the correct way to do it is

```
orders = Order.all
orders.each do |order|
  order.data["size"] = "400"
  order.save
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Loops through each order
Eg:

```
orders = Order.all
orders.each do |order|
  order.data[:size] = "400"
  order.save
end
```

Also, "`serialize :data`" in your Order model if not added

Comment: Yes but what if the data I want to update is inside a JSON string of one columns?

Comment: I have updated my answer please check if it works for you.